# ThreeJS : Culling hide a mesh which is not visible to the user

Tags: three.js

I'm working in threejs occlusion culling where I want to hide the object which is not visible to the view of the user. In this scenario, If I hide the element, I think the data of the element will be presented in the DOM which inturn it is not optimized and the draw calls will remain the same but only I hide the object. So, I have no idea what must I do with the unwanted object which is not visible to the user, should I have to hide it or what can I do to reduce the call of the object when it's not in the view and bring that back to it's normal state when it's visible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the object is in the camera's view, it's gonna get rendered, regardless of whether it's being occluded by another object in front of it. If you want to change this behavior, you'd need to write an algorithm that checks if it's fully covered. Maybe you could use [`.computeBoundingBox()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.computeBoundingBox) to get the min/max positions and help you determine if it's visible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THREEJS performs frustum culling by default.

It will still do a bounding box/frustum check during render to see if the object became visible.

If you want to avoid that, you can set .frustumCulled = false on your object, and then toggle the .visible flag on the object yourself, according to your algorithm.

Comment: If I change the visible flag of the object, will does that gets counts (in draw counts) while rendering? @manthrax

Comment: It shouldn't add a drawcall. To skip matrix updates, set matrixAutoUpdate = false as wel..